# Flask returns page after form submit but does not refresh

Tags: python, html, forms, flask

I have a register page with a form. Upon submit, it will call from Flask the register function. This function will then return a `url_for("index")`. From my Terminal, it does return `GET / HTTP/1.1" 200`. The problem is that the page does not redirect. I have tried entering the index page directly with no issues at all. It also returns `GET / HTTP/1.1" 200` in the terminal. The only issue is after submitting the form. It even reaches the `print("reached")` I made but the page still does not redirect.

For the form's action attribute, I have tried `index`, `/`, `url_for("index")`, `url_for("register")` but to no avail. Codes are show below. Thank you.

**register.html**

```
<form
    action="{{ url_for('register') }}"
    method="POST"
    class="u-clearfix u-form-horizontal u-form-spacing-15 u-inner-form"
    style="padding: 15px"
>
    <div class="u-form-group u-form-name">
        <input
            type="text"
            placeholder="Enter Address"
            id="name-558c"
            name="IP"
            class="u-border-1 u-border-grey-30 u-input u-input-rectangle"
            required=""
        />
    </div>
    <div class="u-form-group u-form-submit">
        <a class="u-btn u-btn-submit u-button-style">Submit</a>
        <input
            type="submit"
            value="Submit"
            class="u-form-control-hidden"
        />
    </div>
</form>
```

**app.py**

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    print("reached")
    return render_template("index.html", participant=participant.getall(), visit=visitList)

@app.route('/register', methods=["POST", "GET"])
def register():
    if request.method == "POST":
        #dosomething
        return redirect(url_for("index"))
    else:
        return render_template("register.html")
```

Comment: Can you post all your app.py codes?

Answer (score 0):

It has to do something with your attributes you try to transmit to `index.html` because all your code is correct and should work.

Comment: Yea I'm not sure what it is. I removed the attributes and it still does not work. Entering `index.html` directly works. It does not work only when I try to redirect after submitting the form.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
return redirect("/")
```

instead of:

```
redirect(url_for("index"))
```

Also, i think you don't necessarily need the form "target" attribute.